# My ASP.NET project gets a lot of error. Why?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, assembly-references

I made an asp.net website from visual studio 2012 last night and it works perfectly fine. I committed my project in bitbucket then pushed it but when i cloned my code and tried to build and run my project, it gets a lot of error about namespaces and stuff. Why is that? The original files works fine. First I thought maybe I made mistakes, so i tried to commit/push another new project(the default application given from visual studio 2012), but when i clone it, it is still the same error i get. Here are the errors:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zn1qbx8kr3avc2/errors.PNG

Do i need to install the packages every time i clone my project?

Answer (score 4):

In nuget options, you can set up to [Enabling Package Restore During Build](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) :

[image]

This will set up your project to maintain packages list, and to redownload missing packages.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply! i tried enabling package restore. As i said, the original project works fine but the clone is not working. I still get same errors and warnings even i enable the Package restore :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with BitBucket, but from the looks of the errors, it appears your missing a lot of your dll's. One thing to check would be ensure that your referenced dll's are set to Copy Local = true. (Solution explorer -> References -> Right Click Dll -> Properties -> Copy Local = True). That should ensure that wherever your copy/publish the solution, the dll's go with it.

Comment: Hi! I also tried copying the references to local. Still when I clone my copy from bitbucket, i get those errors:-(